# adjusting Pop up window position based on page scroll position and closing by clicking out.

Tags: javascript, html, popup

So I know there are plenty of feeds about these issues and I've been through most of them yet I can't make it work. I get really lost with .js.

So I'm using very simple pop up windows that provide more contents on a topic by cicking on the title of the topic. I'm using a simple css code:

```
.black_overlay {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0%;
  left: 0%;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
  z-index: 1001;
  -moz-opacity: 0.8;
  opacity: .80;
  filter: alpha(opacity=80);
}
.white_content {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  left: 20%;
  top:25%;
  width: 70%;
  height: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  border: 6px solid #ed7d86;
  background-color: white;
  text-align: center;
  z-index: 1002;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

And html:

```
<div class="flex-item">
    <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('TITLE').style.display='block';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='block'">TITLE</a> 
    <div id="TITLE" class="white_content">Something else about TITLE. 
<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="document.getElementById('TITLE').style.display='none';
document.getElementById('fade').style.display='none'">Close</a></div>
</div>
```

This code works great until I try it on elements that are lower on the page in which case the box obviously continue showing at the set top and left position, which means that I have to scroll back up to see it. If I get rid of top and left conditions, I just end up with the box showing up randomly at some corner of the page.

I also want people to be able to leave the box just by clicking on the black_overlay area. Can anyone recommend a fix that would work with my code?

Answer (score 0):

Ah well, not much success with my question. Wanted to let you know that I changed the position of the .white_content to fixed and it solved my problem for positioning. I'm still working on closing the window by clicking outside the box without changing all my code.